Is there a way to split text in a cell?
I am doing a survey on Microsoft Forms and the responses are coming through as one string in one cell; as follows:
Product1;Product2;Product3;Product4,...

Is there an way in excel to split these individual strings into individual columns?










Product1
Product2
Product3




TextToColumns in the data tab.

Or using the following formula : =INDEX(TEXTSPLIT($A2,";"),COLUMN(A1)) the reason why i have wrapped within INDEX() because you have tagged Excel Tables otherwise. TEXTSPLIT(A2,";")

And if you are on an older version of Excel you can use find(), left(), right() and mid().

Several ways.

textsplit fn - Per comment above (source: @MB)
textsplit as array fn: if you wish to apply as an array function across many cell (say B2:b200), thne you need to revise the approach, e.g.


= let(x_, b3:B200,y_,lambda(a_,textsplit(",",1,a_))),y_)



FilterXML (if you don't have Office 365 compatible version of Excel nor were your signed up to Insider Office initiative to experiment with beta version functions/office features)


= Filterxml("<x><y>" & Substitute(A1,";","</y><y>")&"</y></x>,"//y")


See 8 ways including above I'm sure to split text here
PS - composed freehand - kindly ensure veracity/operability by testing. revert if issue(s)
Hopefully not ☺ ta
